# Where has precise gone from https://archive.Ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/dists

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I've been trying to download precise for my gitian VM for compiling my crypto for windows. I have successfully done it multiple time in the past and even again the other week, the problem is when I run

```
bin/make-base-vm --lxc --arch amd64 --suite precise
```

in cd gitian-builder it now gives me the error

```
Failed getting release file http://127.0.0.1:3142/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
```

I went on the link http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ and can no longer see precise. I found the same files on another link: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/ and it clearly shows precise as a dist. I thought i can then change the link in the make-base-vm file inside gitian-builder/bin so it would run the link with precise inside so it can then get ahold of release but it wont work due to a key error.

Answer (score 5):

Precise can be found on [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/), where all the obsolete Ubuntu versions dwell.

However, Precise went EoL in 2017, five years ago. There might be a good reason to use that version, but more often than not there isn't any.